# Is there anywhere in Toronto where I can sell Moroccan dirhams (MAD)?

Tags: money, exchange, toronto

Do places like Thomas Cook even have Moroccan money?  This is Toronto, Canada I'm wondering about.  I'm looking to get rid of MAD money.  But it would be interesting to know who sells it too.

Comment: Are you wanting to buy or sel Morrocan money?

Comment: Sell.  Pardon the delay but I couldn't get on the site for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

You theoretically are [not allowed to export Moroccan Dirhams abroad](http://www.visitmorocco.com/index.php/eng/I-get-information/Before-leaving/Money-exchanging-currency-and-banks). Therefore, unless you find someone who will travel to Morocco where he/she can use these dirhams, I don't think you can exchange them.

Anyway, I don't think you can expect an organisation to officially accept dirhams as a means of payment nor for exchange out of Morocco.

Comment: I don't want to use it as payment at a store...just have less than $20 worth and I wanted to turn into CAD.

Comment: Whoa, can't even export one dirham?

Comment: @verve yeah, that's pretty common with a few countries. South Africa used to be like that with their Rand (not sure if they still are)

Comment: @Mark:  is there a specific purpose why countries don't like their money exported?

Comment: @verve well for one, it means they have to keep making more as it doesn't all come back.  :) But there are other economic reasons too - probably a good question for money.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Toronto is one of the most multicultural cities in the world.

This means there is very probably a Moroccan expat community in Toronto. Canada bing partly francophone is probably in your favour too.

I have successfully changed Australian dollars to South Korean won in a Korean supermarket in the next suburb from where I live so given that `MAD` are officially not convertible this is possibly your best bet.

The other possibility of course is to find somebody who's travelling to Morocco soon. If none of your friends or their friends is planning to, you could see if there are CouchSurfing meetups. Toronto is bound to have some. There you will not only have fun and meet interesting people, but some may be Moroccan or travellers intending to go to Morocco as one of their destinations.

Either way you can offer to exchange at official rates so neither of you makes a profit, unlike with a bank or exchange bureau - so it would be a win-win.